# ASPMvc Routing Issues with legacy url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, query-string

I have got a legacy url that I cannot change, which is output on a page which needs to now post to a new MVC version of the page:

http://somesite.com/somepage?some-guid=xxxx-xxxx

Now I am trying to map this to a new controller but I need to get the some-guid into my controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplaySomething(Guid myGuid)
    {
        var someResult = DoSomethingWithAGuid(myGuid);
        ...
    }
}
```

I can change the controller and routes as much as I like, however the legacy url cannot change. So I am a bit stumped as to how I can get access to the some-guid.

I have tried routing with the ?some-guid={myGuid} but the routing doesn't like the ?, so then I tried to let it autobind, but as it contains hyphens it doesn't seem to bind. I was wondering if there was any type of attribute I could use to hint that it should bind from a part of the querystring...

Any help would be great...

Comment: Caveat that you should be aware of: The name of the method parameter in the Action is very important and must match the query parameter passed in the URL. If these are different, then the automatic data binding will not happen - the Routing system queries the RouteData collection for keys which are essentially the parameter names in the method. If the entry is found (which will only happen if the query string parameter matched the method parameter name), then the value is bound automatically to the method parameter. 


In your case, the URL should have query string "myGuid" & not "some-guid"

Comment: Yeah, but as some-guid is not a valid name, I thought it may do what webforms used to do with invalid element names and just strip the "-" out of the variable, however it doesn't seem to. Also to my knowledge MVC is clever enough to know what type you are passing in and what type you expect and just marry them up, although I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought you would have done a route a bit like this..

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RouteName", // Name the route
                "somepage/{some-guid}", // the Url
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "DisplaySomething", some-guid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The {some-guid} part of URL matches your url parmater and passes it to the controller.

So if you have your action like so :

```
public ActionResult DisplaySomething(Guid some-guid)
    {
        var someResult = DoSomethingWithAGuid(some-guid);
        ...
    }
```

Give that a go and see how you get on..

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Somepage", // Route name
  "simepage", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "MyController", action = "DisplaySomething"
);
```

And then in your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public ActionResult DisplaySomething(Guid myGuid)
    {
        var someResult = DoSomethingWithAGuid(myGuid);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would it know what myGuid is in the example above? as the variable on the querystring in the example above is called some-guid. The ideal route would be "/somepage/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-..." so the Guid could just be put in as part of the routing and extract the variable from it, however as mentioned previously I cannot change the url...

Comment: Can you use Url Rewriting to put it into the format above? http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute("SomePageRoute","Somepage", 
   new { controller = "MyController", action = "DisplaySomething" });
```

And then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplaySomething() {
   Guid sGuid = new Guid(Request.QueryString["some-guid"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Again Guid some-guid is not valid c#. The first solution would probably work but it cuts out the autobinder which I would ideally like to make use of.